# Genus and arithmetic genus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

In the Wikipedia of [Arithmetic genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_genus), for a complex projective manifold of complex dimension 1, the arithmetic genus satisfies $\chi=1-g$.

I also see the relation $\chi=2-2g$ for a connected, orientable surface ([Genus(mathematics)-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29)).

Are the Euler characteristics the same and the arithmetic genus is different from the genus? Or the Euler characteristics are different, and there is only one genus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say for a compact Riemann surface $X$ there are 3 different genus: the number of holes, the $g$ appearing in Riemann-Roch (the main parameter of the function field), and the integer computed from the degree and singular points of a plane curve defining $X$. Then it is up to several theorems to relate those things together (Riemann-Hurwitz)